# How do brc20 wallets query the chain?

Tags: blockchain, ordinals

I'm having a look over [OrdPay Wallet](https://ordpay.net/) which is an extension wallet for interacting with ordinals on the bitcoin network. How can sites like these query the bitcoin ordinal chain and see that I have an ordinal inside my wallet?

I come from an EVM industry where it's super easy to check NFTs on the explorer, but not so with ordinals. Can someone explain?

Comment: please reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=596InlNtfD0

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because BRC20 is a notably broken design that was initiated by Craig Wright a notably anti-Bitcoin character

Answer (score -4):

It appears that you reference "BRC20" to a non-standard or less well-known token standard. However, here's the general way information on Bitcoin-based wallets interact with the Bitcoin blockchain.

Bitcoin wallets, including those used by services like OrdPay, query the Bitcoin blockchain generally by:

- *Connect to a Bitcoin node*: Bitcoin wallets connect to Bitcoin nodes, which are computers running the Bitcoin client software and maintaining a copy of the entire blockchain. The wallet can connect to a local node or use a remote node via an API.
- *Send requests to the Bitcoin node*: The wallet sends requests to the connected Bitcoin node using the appropriate protocol or API. The most common protocol used is JSON-RPC, similar to Ethereum. However, Bitcoin also supports other protocols like REST or WebSocket-based APIs.
- *Craft the request*: To query the Bitcoin blockchain, the wallet constructs a request specifying the desired information. For example, to check the balance of a specific address, the wallet can use the getaddressinfo or getreceivedbyaddress method, providing the Bitcoin address as a parameter.
- *Send the request*: The wallet sends the request to the Bitcoin node over the chosen protocol (e.g., JSON-RPC). The node processes the request and retrieves the requested information from the blockchain.
- *Receive and process the response*: The wallet receives the response from the Bitcoin node, containing the queried data, such as the address balance or transaction history. The wallet then parses and processes the response to extract the relevant information.
- *Display the queried data*: Once the wallet has the necessary information, it can display it to the user, such as the Bitcoin balance or transaction details associated with the queried address.

Regarding OrdPay or similar services, it's important to note that "ordinal" is not a recognized term in the context of cryptocurrencies or blockchain technology. If you meant "Bitcoin" instead, these services typically query the Bitcoin blockchain by interacting with Bitcoin nodes, as explained above, to verify and retrieve transaction details associated with your wallet address.

Please provide additional clarification if "ordinal" refers to something specific that I may not be aware of, so I can provide more accurate information.